# Can require_once be used with symbolic links?

Tags: php, linux, lamp

On a CentOS LAMP box, trying to get require_once to work inside a script in PHP5. If the file to be included is not a in symlinked directory, it works fine, but if the file to be required is in a directory found via a symbolic link, it fails to find it.

Is this a limitation of require_once and symbolic links?

EDIT - Thanks for the input, all. I think it's most likely a permissions thing after reading those

Answer (score 4):

Can't you do something like the following?

```
   if (is_link($path))
   {
      $path = readlink($path);
   }
   require_once($path);
```

Comment: In my MacOS/Apache/PHP symbolic links are rendered as binary files (not the destination file). I have to add this scrit to follow the original file and load it accordingly. The same problem happens when I load a file from the tree menu in Sublime Text Editor.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, require_once can use symbolic links just fine. I'm using include_once with some symbolic links in a WordPress MU install and it works just fine - I can't imagine why require_once would function differently than include_once in that respect.

Any chance you've got [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) restrictions set?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there aren't. Are the permissions the same as when you don't use the sym link?

Answer (score 0):

require, require_once, include etc. all allow requiring symlinked files (both directly symlinked or within a symlinked directory). If you get this error, double-check your symlink. There's a good chance your symlink is broken/incorrect.